# How to fetch JSON object correctly in place of [Object object]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Building a simple web scraper with mongoDB.

API returns JSON object in correct format, however, on `append` it to a bootstrap card on the page getting `[Object object]`.

Here's my JS on browser:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $("#show-articles").on("click", () => {
        $.get("/all/articles", (data) => {
            data.forEach(data => {
                articleCardDisplay(data);
            });
        });
    });
});


function articleCardDisplay(data) {
    // Function for display article data and generating a bootstrap card
    let card = $("<div class='col l4 s6'>")
    card += $("<div class='card bg-light mb-3' style='max-width: 18rem;'>");
    card += $("<div class='card-header'>Liquor.com</div>");
    card += $("<div class='card-body'>");
    card += $("<h5 class='card-title'>" + data.headline + "</h5>");
    card += $("<p class='card-text'>" + data.summary + "</p>");
    card += $("</div>")
    card += $("</div>")
    card += $("</div>")

    // Append the new article card to the article section div
    $("#articleContainer").append(card)
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated thank you!

EDIT here is the MongoDB format:

```js
exports.scraper = (req, res) => {
    // AXIOS get request to liquor.com news article section
    axios.get("https://www.liquor.com/discover/#gs.NjJIXmk").then(response => {
        // Load the Liquor.com HTML into cheerio
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

        // Loop through each article card
        $("div.card").each((i, element) => {
            // assign each piece of html we want too a variable
            let headline = $(element).find("div.copy").children("h3").text();
            let summary = $(element).find("div.copy").children("div.archive-item-text").text();
            let url = $(element).find("div.image").children("a.overlay").attr("href");

            // console.log("Headline: " + headline);
            // console.log("Summary: " + summary);
            // console.log("URL: " + url);

            // Insert into MongoDB
            Article.collection.insert({
                headline: headline,
                summary: summary,
                url: url
            }, (err, inserted) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("scrape complete");
                }
            });
        });
        
        res.render("index");
    });
}

// ========= GET ROUTE FOR all/articles ======== //

exports.allArticles = (req, res) => {
    Article.collection.find({}).toArray((error, found) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            res.send(found);
        }
    })
}
```

The goal is to take the data and generate a bootstrap card for each article JSON object, the back end works and the array of objects is received at the browser's console, but when tried to use the `articleCardDisplay` function it spits out `[Object object]`. Tried to add `JSON.Stringify(data)`, but same response.

Comment: can you provide format of data or any working code plunker etc

Comment: Not sure, but I think you should create the markup as plain text first and then apply jquery magic: `markup='<div>... </div>';card=$(markup);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning wrong HTML to card using `$(<HTML element>)`.

Just use this:

```
function articleCardDisplay(data) {
    // Function for display article data and generating a bootstrap card
    let card = "<div class='col l4 s6'>";
    card += "<div class='card bg-light mb-3' style='max-width: 18rem;'>";
    card += "<div class='card-header'>Liquor.com</div>";
    card += "<div class='card-body'>";
    card += "<h5 class='card-title'>" + data.headline + "</h5>";
    card += "<p class='card-text'>" + data.summary + "</p>";
    card += "</div>";
    card += "</div>";
    card += "</div>";

    // Append the new article card to the article section div
    $("#articleContainer").append(card)
}
```

Comment: This is the story of my life when it comes to coding lol, one small mistake and I never catch it lol thank you so much!, still pretty new to coding

Comment: @JacobCadiente checkout this repository, I created it keeping in mind issues faced by starter in nodeJS and web-application https://github.com/navinbisht1992/nodejs-frontend-sample